# How to make a transparent plot

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to plot 4 different states that are overlapping. How can I make to show all 4 states on this plot

Please find below my sample data:

```
dput (head(dfs_melted, 20) )
structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), time = structure(c(81L, 
81L, 81L, 81L, 81L, 81L, 81L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 
83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L), .Label = c("04:00", "04:15", "04:30", 
"04:45", "05:00", "05:15", "05:30", "05:45", "06:00", "06:15", 
"06:30", "06:45", "07:00", "07:15", "07:30", "07:45", "08:00", 
"08:15", "08:30", "08:45", "09:00", "09:15", "09:30", "09:45", 
"10:00", "10:15", "10:30", "10:45", "11:00", "11:15", "11:30", 
"11:45", "12:00", "12:15", "12:30", "12:45", "13:00", "13:15", 
"13:30", "13:45", "14:00", "14:15", "14:30", "14:45", "15:00", 
"15:15", "15:30", "15:45", "16:00", "16:15", "16:30", "16:45", 
"17:00", "17:15", "17:30", "17:45", "18:00", "18:15", "18:30", 
"18:45", "19:00", "19:15", "19:30", "19:45", "20:00", "20:15", 
"20:30", "20:45", "21:00", "21:15", "21:30", "21:45", "22:00", 
"22:15", "22:30", "22:45", "23:00", "23:15", "23:30", "23:45", 
"00:00", "00:15", "00:30", "00:45", "01:00", "01:15", "01:30", 
"01:45", "02:00", "02:15", "02:30", "02:45", "03:00", "03:15", 
"03:30", "03:45"), class = "factor"), day = structure(c(6L, 2L, 
7L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 
5L, 3L), .Label = c("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
"Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"), class = "factor"), variable = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("husbandworkschedule", "wifesworkschedule", 
"synchronization"), class = "factor"), value = c("Desynchronization", 
"Desynchronization", "Desynchronization", "Desynchronization", 
"Desynchronization", "Desynchronization", "Desynchronization", 
"Desynchronization", "Desynchronization", "Desynchronization", 
"Desynchronization", "Desynchronization", "Desynchronization", 
"Desynchronization", "Desynchronization", "Desynchronization", 
"Desynchronization", "Desynchronization", "Desynchronization", 
"Desynchronization")), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Using the below code I created a ggplot as:

```
windows()

ggplot(dfs_melted , aes(x = time, y = id, fill = value)) +
  geom_col(position = 'identity', alpha = 0.6)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(
   "Wife's work schedule"="#7852A9",
   "Husband's work schedule"="#bec605",
   "Synchronization"="#5DBB63",
  "Desynchronization"="#CB4154"))+
  #coord_polar()+
  facet_wrap(~ day)+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=rel(1.5)), axis.text.y=element_text(size=rel(1.5)))  +scale_x_discrete(breaks =  c("04:00", "08:00",  "12:00", "16:00",  "20:00",  "00:00",  "03:00"),expand = c(-0, 0), name= "Time (hours)")+ scale_y_continuous(expand = c(-0, 0), name = "Household numbers") 
 
  ##############################
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4vJE.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest next approach it looks like you want to see bars per each state. I include dummy data:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Data
dfn <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), time = structure(c(81L, 
81L, 81L, 81L, 81L, 81L, 81L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 
83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 81L, 81L, 81L, 81L, 81L, 81L, 81L, 
82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L
), .Label = c("04:00", "04:15", "04:30", "04:45", "05:00", "05:15", 
"05:30", "05:45", "06:00", "06:15", "06:30", "06:45", "07:00", 
"07:15", "07:30", "07:45", "08:00", "08:15", "08:30", "08:45", 
"09:00", "09:15", "09:30", "09:45", "10:00", "10:15", "10:30", 
"10:45", "11:00", "11:15", "11:30", "11:45", "12:00", "12:15", 
"12:30", "12:45", "13:00", "13:15", "13:30", "13:45", "14:00", 
"14:15", "14:30", "14:45", "15:00", "15:15", "15:30", "15:45", 
"16:00", "16:15", "16:30", "16:45", "17:00", "17:15", "17:30", 
"17:45", "18:00", "18:15", "18:30", "18:45", "19:00", "19:15", 
"19:30", "19:45", "20:00", "20:15", "20:30", "20:45", "21:00", 
"21:15", "21:30", "21:45", "22:00", "22:15", "22:30", "22:45", 
"23:00", "23:15", "23:30", "23:45", "00:00", "00:15", "00:30", 
"00:45", "01:00", "01:15", "01:30", "01:45", "02:00", "02:15", 
"02:30", "02:45", "03:00", "03:15", "03:30", "03:45"), class = "factor"), 
    day = structure(c(6L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 7L, 
    1L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 5L, 
    3L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 5L, 3L
    ), .Label = c("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
    "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"), class = "factor"), variable = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("husbandworkschedule", 
    "wifesworkschedule", "synchronization"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c("Desynchronization", "Desynchronization", "Desynchronization", 
    "Desynchronization", "Desynchronization", "Desynchronization", 
    "Desynchronization", "Desynchronization", "Desynchronization", 
    "Desynchronization", "Desynchronization", "Desynchronization", 
    "Desynchronization", "Desynchronization", "Desynchronization", 
    "Desynchronization", "Desynchronization", "Desynchronization", 
    "Desynchronization", "Desynchronization", "Synchronization", 
    "Synchronization", "Synchronization", "Synchronization", 
    "Synchronization", "Synchronization", "Synchronization", 
    "Synchronization", "Synchronization", "Synchronization", 
    "Synchronization", "Synchronization", "Synchronization", 
    "Synchronization", "Synchronization", "Synchronization", 
    "Synchronization", "Synchronization", "Synchronization", 
    "Synchronization")), row.names = c(NA, -40L), class = "data.frame")
```

The code:

```
ggplot(dfn , aes(x = time, y = id, fill = value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = position_dodge(), alpha = 0.6)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(
    "Wife's work schedule"="#7852A9",
    "Husband's work schedule"="#bec605",
    "Synchronization"="#5DBB63",
    "Desynchronization"="#CB4154"))+
  #coord_polar()+
  facet_wrap(~ day)+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=rel(1.5)),
        axis.text.y=element_text(size=rel(1.5)))  +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks =  c("04:00", "08:00",  "12:00", 
                               "16:00",  "20:00",  "00:00",  "03:00"),
                   expand = c(-0, 0), name= "Time (hours)")+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(-0, 0), name = "Household numbers")
```

The output:

[image]